# Different storyboard's entry points depending on a parameter

Tags: ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, entry-point

I'm developing an app where I need to manage the common scenario of users having to provide credentials to log in and access the main app's functions. This way, the view I need to firstly show the user if she's not logged in is the view to allow her to log in, or the let's call it "dashboard" of the app if the user is already logged in when the app is launched.

How could I handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to pick one scene as your initial scene. This could be a blank scene the immediately segues to the appropriate scene or you could have your "logged in" scene as your initial scene and present your "login" scene modally if required (this is what I would do)

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. I'm trying to handle this directly with storyboard, but the point is that, if the user is logged in, I need to load a tab bar controller, and if she's not, a navigation controller. I added a blank view controller as entry point, with a container view, but storyboard only allows to set an "embed" segue for one of the two possible view controllers I need to load. Is it possible to manage that in storyboard, or only in code-behind?

Comment: You can just manipulate the rootViewController property as per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this in AppDelegate class in applicationDidFinishlaunchingWithOptions method. Dont know this will work. its a hunch. try like this.

```
if(userLoggedIn)
{
  window.rootViewController = [window.rootViewController.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashBoardScreen"];
}
else
{
  window.rootViewController = [window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginSCreen"];
}
```